# ¿Existe algún sitio en Stack Exchange sobre Matemáticas?

Tags: soporte

Hola amigos estoy buscando pero no veo ninguna subforo sobre:

"matemáticas" pero para personas que necesiten preguntar preguntas variadas como de **arimética**,**álegra**,**etcétera** pero sobre cualquier tema del aritmética, etc.

¿Existe? Y si existe ¿cuál es?

Comment: Según entiendo, en Stack Exchange no se usan las palabras foro, subforo y sus variantes para referirnos a los sitios en la red por un lado porque estos sitios no son como los foros web como aquellos con los que están familiarizada mucha gente, por otro lado porque resultada confuso. Ya ocurrió al menos una ocasión en la que una pregunta hablaba de subforos pero se refería a [etiquetas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). En relación a la susodicha ocasión, aparentemente la pregunta en cuestión fué eliminada.

Comment: Hola, si te fijas arriba a la Izquierda, donde dice StackExchange, al hacer click se despliega un menu con un cuadro que dice "buscar una comunidad".. ahi puedes explorar todos sitios disponibles en la red ya sea buscando o scrolleando hacia abajo donde aparece toda la lista.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sí existen:

- Para preguntas de cualquier nivel: https://math.stackexchange.com/
- Para profesionales: https://mathoverflow.net/
- Para maestros: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/
- Historia y ciencia de las matemáticas: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Favor de ver [mi comentario](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1566/existe-alg%c3%ban-sitio-en-stack-exchange-sobre-matem%c3%a1ticas#comment4398_1566) a la pregunta.

Comment: Ya lo vi, pero no lo entiendo. No se llaman subforos, se llaman sitio. ¿Es eso?

Comment: No sé si por subforo el OP se refiere a sitio o a etiqueta. Veo que tu has asumido que se refiere a sitio, lo cual está bien, pero es como "una apuesta"

Comment: Ah. Eso ya lo decidió @fedorqui. Se refiere a sitios de StackExchange. Afortunadamente, porque eso fue justo lo que contesté.

Comment: jeje, pues le faltó "corregir" subforo :D

Comment: Acabo de ver los comentarios de las revisiones. `Sí` con acento gráfico es afirmación, no condicional: Referencia: http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Adwesaq4ND64VT09xQ

Comment: @Rubén, toledano: tenéis razón, edité asumiendo que el OP se refería a sitios. Mi edición surgió de la típica confusión de llamar Stack Overflow al todo, cuando este "todo" es Stack Exchange. A ver qué contesta el OP al comentario de Rubén.

Comment: Quizas sea interesante aclarar que estan en ingles, porque igual accede el OP u otro usuario, a todos los link buscando una en español. Saludos